# Calling a function in another function that is transferred to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to call the function `performSearch ()` by clicking `div` in the component`Item`. The `performSerach ()` function is placed in another `select ()` function. The `select ()` function is passed to the `Item` component. In console.log returns me `active = null`.

**Items**

```
class Items extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      active: null,
            abc: null
    }
  }

  select = (id) => {
    this.setState({
            abc: id
    })
    this.performSearch(id);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get
        axios({
            url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              items: res.data 
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })      
}

performSearch = (id) => {
  axios.get
    axios({
        url: `https://app.com/api/v1/${id}`,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`           
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            active: res.data
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

  render () {
    <div>
            {this.state.items.map((item, index) => 
                <Item
                        select={this.select}
                />
            )} 
    </div>
  }
}
```

**Item**

```
class Item extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div onClick={()=> this.props.select(this.props.item.id)}>

      </div>
    )
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  render () {
    <div>
            {this.state.items.map((item, index) => 
                <Item
                        select={this.select}
                />
            )} 
    </div>
  }
```

Should pass the item the `Item` component:

```
  render () {
    <div>
            {this.state.items.map((item, index) => 
                <Item
                        select={this.select}
                        item={item}
                        key={index}
                />
            )} 
    </div>
  }
```

Or:

```
  render () {
    <div>
            {this.state.items.map((item, index) => 
                <Item
                        select={() => this.select(item.id)}
                />
            )} 
    </div>
  }
```

Comment: I'm curious why second way works, first way doesn't work. 
Could you explain?